# Chrome Extension: sendRequest to content script inside inner iframes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have injected a content script file to all pages and inner iframes using `"all_frames": true` but when I send a request from popup only top window is receiving it. Any idea how can send it to all inner frames or at least last focused window/document?

```
Popup.html (page action):
===========
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {...}, function(response) {...});
});

content_script.js
=================
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({...});
});
```

I have checked that content script is working in inner frames.

I'm trying to retrieve text selection which may be in inner frames.

(By the way I prefer not to open connection by every and all content script, that's a big overhead.)

Comment: In Firefox I simply do `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow` or `document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that one tab can have only one `onRequest` listener. So if you want to send messages to **only** iframe script, and there is only **one** iframe on the page, then you should create a listener inside iframe only:

```
//listen to requests only inside iframe
if(window!=window.top) {
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Now if you want to send requests to **both** parent page and iframe, or there are **many** iframes on the page that need to listen to requests - you need to communicate through [ports](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html#connect).

Ports still have a similar limitation - only one port listener will be called, but you can open many ports. If there is a parent page with only one iframe - you just open two connections on two different ports. But if there are many iframes on the page, and each iframe has subframes - you would need to enumerate all iframes first to create unique ports for each of them.

PS. I am not sure what you meant by

> I prefer not to open connection by every and all content script

but if you want to inject content script on demand, there is  `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggested `executeScript()` instead of `sendRequest()` to communicate to all inner frames, and they send back responses using `sendRequest()`.